# Simple circuit with dependent source interpretation

Tags: circuit-analysis

For the following circuit, taken from the book "Circuit analysis for dummies" what would its BJT transistor counterpart look like (I mean the most basic circuit with the BJT transistor instead of the dependent source)? I'm especially interested in figuring out how the R2 resistor is connected in the circuit with the BJT transistor.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because real circuits cannot contain any current sources, we - at first - can replace the current source Is and the shunt resistor R1 by a corresponding (equivalent) voltage source V3 and a series source resistor Ri. Now - there are two resistors in series (Ri - R2) and the common node labelled as Va is identical to the base node (because the corresponding node voltage Vx acts as an input to the controlled current source).
Therefore, the resistor R2 connects the collector with the base which means: negative feedback.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6vQNL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>